# Having trouble setting headers in a QNetworkRequest

Tags: c++, qt, networking, qt4

I am using the following function to make a post request:

```
bool NewAccountDialog::verifyAccount()
{
    QString loginURL = "https://accounts.craigslist.org/";
    QString USERAGENT = "Mozilla/Firefox 3.6.12";

    // This is all bullshit
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(loginURL);
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", USERAGENT);

    QByteArray data;
    QUrl params;

    params.addQueryItem("inputEmailHandle", accountName->text());
    params.addQueryItem("inputPassword", accountPass->text());
    data.append(params.toString());
    //No idea what this does
    data.remove(0,1);

    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(request,data);

    // Parse reply

    return 1;
}
```

Obviously it's incomplete, but it doesn't compile giving me an error where I run `request.setRawHeader()` complaining there is no function that matches my call:

> /home/brett/projects/CLPoster/CLPoster-build-desktop/../CLPoster/newaccountdialog.cpp:120:
>   error: no matching function for call to
>   `QNetworkRequest::setRawHeader(const char [11], QString&)`

It takes 2 `QByteArrays` as parameters, and the official example even passes it two strings:

```
 request.setRawHeader("Last-Modified", "Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT");
```

Not that it should matter, but I've tried that and still get the same error. Is my Qt broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the second parameter (`USERAGENT`). A `QByteArray` can be constructed from a char array, but not from a `QString` (see [`QByteArray`'s documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qbytearray.html)). You need either to use [`QString::toAscii()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#toAscii), `QString::toLatin1()` or something similar, or to make `USERAGENT` a `char*`:

```
 const char* USERAGENT = "Mozilla/Firefox 3.6.12";
```